# Remove star and empty line using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe i want remove star and all the empty line in localisation. I have to create two columns "temp" and "word".

"temp" contains all the lines after the first line break and the column "word" represents all the words of this list found in "temp":

```py
words = ['SECTION 11', 'CONE', 'BELLY', 'FIXED PLAN']
```

My input:

[image]

Ouput expected: I have to replace star with empty in the "word" column:

[image]

I try this

```py
def SplitRow(description):
    import re
    substring=re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9,\*\s]+",description.split("\n")[1])
    if description.split("\n")[1] in substring:
        if re.findall(r"^\s?\*\$", description.split("\n")[1]):
            return "etoile"+description.split("\n")[1]
        if re.findall(r"Localisation\s*:.*", description.split("\n")[1]):
            return description.split("\n")[2]
        return description.split("\n")[1]
```

but it doesn't work as there are a lot of rows with `None`:

[image]

Comment: In general, dont post images of code; see [here](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) for more info.

Comment: @rv.kvetch I have replaced the main part with text. However, in this case, code as text is not really necessary to understand the problem and help OP, IMHO.

Comment: Well, for future reference I guess the point is that someone else shouldn't have to spend time transcribing the code in the question. @Mohammed Grini please take note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
df['temp'] = df['localisation'].str.replace(r'^.*\n', '', regex=True)
words = ['SECTION 11', 'CONE', 'BELLY', 'FIXED PLAN']
df['word'] = df['temp'].str.findall(fr'(?<!\w)(?:{"|".join([re.escape(w) for w in words])})(?!\w)').str.join(', ')
```

*Details*:

- `.str.replace(r'^.*\n', '', regex=True)` removes the first line with the line break
- `.str.findall(fr'(?<!\w)(?:{"|".join([re.escape(w) for w in words])})(?!\w)')` extracts all occurrences of the `words` as whole words (due to `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` unambiguous word boundaries) in the `temp` column while escaping all non-word chars in the `words`.
- `.str.join(', ')` at the end of the last code line is used to join the found list of matches with a comma + space. You may further adjust what to join the matches with if you edit the argument in the `.str.join()` part.